# Sagepay ITokenRemoveRequest issue

Tags: opayo

I am facing an issue when trying to delete a TOKEN on Sagepay on development environment. I am using Server Integration method to remove the TOKEN.

Below is the code where in I am building the request and calling the process method from Sagepay API jar.

```
final ConfigProperties properties = configLookupService.loadConfigProperties();
final IServerApi api = ApiFactory.getServerApi();
api.configure(properties.getRawProperties());
final ITokenRemoveRequest iTokenRemoveRequest = createDataForSagepayTokenDeletion(properties, api, token);
IBasicResult iBasicResult = api.process(iTokenRemoveRequest);
```

Below is the error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown message class interface com.sagepay.sdk.api.messages.ITokenRemoveRequest
>               at com.sagepay.sdk.impl.Marshaller.getProtocolMessageForClass(Marshaller.java:205)
>               at com.sagepay.sdk.impl.Marshaller.marshal(Marshaller.java:165)
>               at com.sagepay.sdk.impl.ApiImpl.sendRequest(ApiImpl.java:414)
>               at com.sagepay.sdk.impl.ApiImpl.process(ApiImpl.java:266)
>               at com.exertis.sagepay.payment.service.impl.DefaultSagepayPaymentService.removeSagepayToken(DefaultSagepayPaymentService.java:670).

It is evident from the stackTrace that,
    Inside com.sagepay.sdk.impl.Marshaller , CLASS_TO_MSG_MAP does not have the ITokenRemoveRequest as valid class hence it fails.

It will very helpful, if some one can help us on this. Or if some one else has faced the same issue and have managed to resolve it.